# no sumas cadenas string while

Tags: java, string, while, char

Porque el string caracteres no suma correctamente y solo imprime un solo caracter por linea?

```
private void btnEscaleraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
String caracteres=("");
int num =0;
String pregEscalones = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cuantos escalones desea? ");
int escalones = Integer.parseInt(pregEscalones);
String pregCaracter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("que caracter desea usar? ");
char charCaracter = pregCaracter.charAt(0);
String caracter = String.valueOf(charCaracter);

while(num <= escalones)
{
 caracteres = caracteres + caracter + "\n";
 txtEscalera.setText(caracteres);
 num++;
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué agregas `\n`?

Comment: porque estas mandando un caracter por linea.. que querias hacer???

Comment: es una esclaera de caracteres tipo:
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
cada espacio es un salto de linea pero no sale en el comentario

Comment: En un JTextField no puedes ver varias líneas, en un JTextArea sí.

Answer (score 4):

un solo while no es suficiente, debe haber un while que cree cada escalón y otro que añada cada carácter de cada escalón. También pone txtEscalera.setText(caracteres) dentro del bucle, cuando se podría hacer cuando el bucle haya terminado.

```
    int Escalon = 0; //Escalon que se modifica
    int NumeroEscalon = 10; //Cuantos escalones debe tener
    char Char = 'a';            
    String Escalera = ""; 
    
    //Creando la escalera
    while (Escalon < NumeroEscalon)
    {
        Escalon++;
        int Caracter = 0;
       
        while (Caracter < Escalon)
        {
            Escalera += Char;
            Caracter ++;
        }
        Escalera +=  "\n";
    }
    Escalera += "\n"; //Aqui tiene la escalera.
    txtEscalera.setText(Escalera);
```